# Implementing multiple synonym_path for single index in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

I am trying to achieve multiple `synonym_path` for a single index in elasticsearch.

```
"settings": {
"index": {
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "synonym": {
        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "filter": ["synonym"]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "synonym": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
              "ignore_case": true
            }},
          {
            "synonym": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "synonyms2.txt",
              "ignore_case": true
          }}]
      }
    }
  }
}
},
  "mappings": {
    "animals": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "String",
          "analyzer": "synonym"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried the snippet above using JSON Sense in Chrome but it generated a `TokenFilter [bool] must have a type associated with it` error.

Is there other way to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` section in the `analysis` section is not meant to contain the Query DSL but [token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenfilters.html) definitions.

In your case, you need to re-create your index with the following settings:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonyms": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "synonym1",
              "synonym2"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
            "synonym1": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
              "ignore_case": true
            },
            "synonym2": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "synonyms2.txt",
              "ignore_case": true
            }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "animals": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "synonyms"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a `TokenFilter [0] must have a type associated with it` error thrown.
What does this mean? :)

Comment: My bad, a small typo, sorry. Go ahead and try again

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Val!

Comment: Hello, can you confirm we can't provide a list of files to "synonyms_path" ? Thanks

Comment: No, it's just a single file